# How can I tell if my mobile network is available or not on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

i have one application in iphone in which i have to show notification when mobile SIM network is not present .i want also notification when network back .

and how can also i know how much other network available ?

Comment: What is a "mobile SIM network"?

Comment: i mean by SIM card network is any network we use for call and messages. like in india there is VODAPHONE ,AIRTEL ,BSNL ,MSNL ,etc this all company provide network card (SIM card) by which we have network and we can call . i m taliking about this .    i want to know user is able to call or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pull the code I needed out of the sample project [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) From Apple.

Comment: i know about this ...but i m talking about mobile SIM card network ..not wifi . this show me notification about WIFI network. or its same work for Mobile Sim card network ?

Comment: Yes, the code tells you if you have no internet, WWAN (internet via Edge, 3G or other kind of mobile fone internet) or WiFi.  You can also set it up to send out notifications when the connectivity state changes.